# Declarar variables global en C#

Tags: c#, variables, variables-globales

Tengo dos funciones, una realiza el calculo, y en la siguiente quiero almacenar los datos iniciales.
El caso es que en la segunda función, no me toma las variables, ya que encuentra ambigüedad.

Una de las variables que necesito almacenar en la base de datos ,en la segunda funcion, es `Interes`, por ejemplo

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Asigno valores
            double importeSolicitado = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            double Interes = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text) / 1200, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            double Cuotas = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            //Declaro las variables
            double iva = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            object id_cliente = pers_nombreComboBox.SelectedValue;
            


            //Asigno a Saldo el Importe Solicitado, ya que despues lo usare como Saldo y no como Importe Solicitado
            double Saldo = importeSolicitado;
            //Calculo la cuota
            double CalculoCuota = Saldo * (Math.Pow(1 + Interes, Cuotas) * Interes / (Math.Pow(1 + Interes, Cuotas) - 1));
            double CFT = 0;

            //Por cada cuota, realizo el calculo de todas las columnas
            for (int i = 0; i < Cuotas; i++)
            {
                double montoInteres = Saldo * Interes;
                double Amortizacion = CalculoCuota - montoInteres;
                double montoIva = 0;
                //Si no posee Iva
                if (iva == 0) {
                    montoIva = 0.00;
                        }
                //Si posee IVA
                else
                {
                   montoIva = iva / 100 * montoInteres;
                }
                
                double totalPagar = montoInteres + Amortizacion + montoIva;
                
                CFT =CFT+totalPagar;
                //Lleno la fila correspondiente
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, Saldo, montoInteres, Amortizacion, montoIva, totalPagar);

                Saldo -= Amortizacion; //Le reasingo a Saldo el valor que le corresponde para la siguiente cuota
            }

            double CFTotal =(CFT/importeSolicitado-1)*100 ;
            CFTotal=Math.Round(CFTotal, 2);
            label7.Text = CFTotal.ToString();
            

        }

    
        

        private void Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
            string stringInsert = "Insert into operacion (pers_id,oper_importe_prestamo,oper_tasa,oper_cant_cuotas,oper_iva,oper_CFT) values ('" + id_cliente + "','" + importeSolicitado + "','" + Interes + "','" + Cuotas + "','" + email + "');";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(stringInsert, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Como puedo solucionarlo, ya que las operaciones no quiero repetirlas, si bien podría asignar cada una de las variables, lo veo innecesario.
La solucion seria que las variables de la primer función sean globales, para poder utilizarlas luego

Comment: Declara las variables Fuera de los Métodos Para hacerlas globales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare las variables enseguida de la declaración de la clase de la siguiente forma:

```
public class NombreDeSuClase
    {


        double importeSolicitado = 0;
        double Interes = 0;
        double Cuotas = 0;
        //Declaro las variables
        double iva = 0;
        object id_cliente = 0;



        //Asigno a Saldo el Importe Solicitado, ya que despues lo usare como Saldo y no como Importe Solicitado
        double Saldo = 0;
        //Calculo la cuota
        double CalculoCuota = 0;
        double CFT = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Asigno valores
             importeSolicitado = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
             Interes = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text) / 1200, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
             Cuotas = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            //Declaro las variables
             iva = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
             id_cliente = pers_nombreComboBox.SelectedValue;



            //Asigno a Saldo el Importe Solicitado, ya que despues lo usare como Saldo y no como Importe Solicitado
             Saldo = importeSolicitado;
            //Calculo la cuota
             CalculoCuota = Saldo * (Math.Pow(1 + Interes, Cuotas) * Interes / (Math.Pow(1 + Interes, Cuotas) - 1));
             CFT = 0;

            //Por cada cuota, realizo el calculo de todas las columnas
            for (int i = 0; i < Cuotas; i++)
            {
                double montoInteres = Saldo * Interes;
                double Amortizacion = CalculoCuota - montoInteres;
                double montoIva = 0;
                //Si no posee Iva
                if (iva == 0)
                {
                    montoIva = 0.00;
                }
                //Si posee IVA
                else
                {
                    montoIva = iva / 100 * montoInteres;
                }

                double totalPagar = montoInteres + Amortizacion + montoIva;

                CFT = CFT + totalPagar;
                //Lleno la fila correspondiente
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, Saldo, montoInteres, Amortizacion, montoIva, totalPagar);

                Saldo -= Amortizacion; //Le reasingo a Saldo el valor que le corresponde para la siguiente cuota
            }

            double CFTotal = (CFT / importeSolicitado - 1) * 100;
            CFTotal = Math.Round(CFTotal, 2);
            label7.Text = CFTotal.ToString();


        }




        private void Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
            string stringInsert = "Insert into operacion (pers_id,oper_importe_prestamo,oper_tasa,oper_cant_cuotas,oper_iva,oper_CFT) values ('" + id_cliente + "','" + importeSolicitado + "','" + Interes + "','" + Cuotas + "','" + email + "');";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(stringInsert, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Ahora bien. Hay varias cosas que podría mejorar en su código. Una de ellas y la más importante es parametrizar las consultas a base de datos para evitar inyecciones sql: https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/sql/como-creo-una-consulta-sql-parametrizada-por-que-deberia/958225022/. También podría crear un objeto de tipo Operacion por decir algo y meterle todas las propiedades que necesita para esas operaciones en lugar de declarar todas esas variables, para eso existe la programación orientada a objetos.
Para evitar errores podría usar el método Double.TryParse para los datos double y garantizar que siempre sea un dato double: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1 y también sería bueno que echara un vistazo a cosas chevere como async/await : https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/async-y-await-en-c-como-manejar-asincronismo-en-net-de-manera-facil.aspx y el using statement para asegurar un scope seguro a las conexiones a base de datos:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes declararlas fuera de los métodos:

```
public tuClase{
 //las variables globales se declaran fuera de los métodos entonces te queda así:
 double variableUno = tu valor;
 string variableDos = "tu valor";
 
 public BotonLoQueSea(eventos){}
}
```